# Couldn't get rid of (_tkinter.TclError: bad event type or keysym "UP") problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, onkeypress

I am running a Linux mint for the first time . I tried coding a python problem but for two days I am continiously facing problems due to Linux interface please

This is my code:-

```
    import turtle
    import time
    boxsize=200
    caught=False
    score=0
    #function that are called in keypress
    def up():
        mouse.forward(10)
        checkbound()

    def left():
        move.left(45)

    def right():
        move.right(45)

    def back():
        mouse.backward(10)
        checkbound()

    def quitTurtles():
        window.bye()
    #stop the mouse from leaving the square set size
    def checkbound():
        global boxsize
        if mouse.xcor()>boxsize:
            mouse.goto(boxsize, mouse.ycor())
        if mouse.xcor()<-boxsize:
             mouse.goto(-boxsize, mouse.ycor())
        if mouse.ycor()>boxsize:
            mouse.goto(mouse.xcor(),boxsize)

        if mouse.ycor()<-boxsize:
            mouse.goto(mouse.xcor(),-boxsize)

    #set up screen
    window=turtle.Screen()
    mouse=turtle.Turtle()
    cat=turtle.Turtle()
    mouse.penup()
    mouse.penup()
    mouse.goto(100,100)

    #add key listeners
    window.onkeypress(up ,'UP')
    window.onkeypress(right ,'left')
    window.onkeypress(left ,'Right')
    window.onkeypress(back ,'DOWN')
    window.onkeypress(quitTurtles, "Escape")

    difficulty=window.numinput("difficulty","Enter a difficulty from 1 to 5",minval=1,maxval=5)
    window.listen()
    #main loop
    #note how it changes with difficulty
    while not caught:
        cat.setheading(cat.towards(mouse))
        cat.forward(8+diffficulty)
        score=score+1
        if cat.distance(mouse)<5:
            caught=true

        time.sleep(0.2-(0.1*difficulty))
    window.textinput("GAME OVER","WELL DONE YOU SCORED:"+str(score*difficulty))
    window.bye()
```

[image: and this the error]

Comment: Key names should be `Up`, `Left` and `Down`.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Thank you so much...It was a silly mistake sorry ..i'll keep that in mind

Comment: I doubt Linux is the problem here--these are just code bugs in Python.

Answer (score 1):

This code has several problems, many of which will keep it from running correctly:

Substituted `move` for `mouse`:

```
def up():
    mouse.forward(10)
    checkbound()

def left():
    move.left(45)
```

Unnecessary `global` declaration as `boxsize` is not assigned:

```
def checkbound():
    global boxsize
```

In code copy-and-paste, didn't change `mouse` to `cat`:

```
mouse=turtle.Turtle()
cat=turtle.Turtle()
mouse.penup()
mouse.penup()
```

The `difficulty` variable not spelled consistently:

```
    cat.forward(8+diffficulty)
    time.sleep(0.2-(0.1*difficulty))
```

Incorrect case for boolean:

```
 caught=true
```

As noted in comments, total inconsistency in key naming case:

```
window.onkeypress(right ,'left')
window.onkeypress(left ,'Right')
window.onkeypress(back ,'DOWN')
```

Bigger picture issues are use of `sleep()` in an event-driven environment and lack of drawn boundaries so player knows the limits.  Rather than address these issues one by one in SO questions, let's rework this code to work within the turtle event environment and be playable as a game:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

BOX_SIZE = 600

# functions that are called in keypress
def up():
    mouse.forward(15)
    checkbound()

def left():
    mouse.left(45)

def right():
    mouse.right(45)

def back():
    mouse.backward(15)
    checkbound()

def checkbound():
    ''' stop the mouse from leaving the square set size '''

    if mouse.xcor() > BOX_SIZE/2:
        mouse.goto(BOX_SIZE/2, mouse.ycor())
    elif mouse.xcor() < -BOX_SIZE/2:
        mouse.goto(-BOX_SIZE/2, mouse.ycor())

    if mouse.ycor() > BOX_SIZE/2:
        mouse.goto(mouse.xcor(), BOX_SIZE/2)
    elif mouse.ycor() < -BOX_SIZE/2:
        mouse.goto(mouse.xcor(), -BOX_SIZE/2)

def move():
    global score

    cat.setheading(cat.towards(mouse))
    cat.forward(2 * difficulty)
    score += 1

    if cat.distance(mouse) < 5:
        screen.textinput("GAME OVER", "WELL DONE YOU SCORED: {}".format(score * difficulty))
        screen.bye()
    else:
        screen.ontimer(move, 200 - 100 * difficulty)

score = 0

# set up screen
screen = Screen()

marker = Turtle()
marker.hideturtle()
marker.penup()
marker.goto(-BOX_SIZE/2, -BOX_SIZE/2)
marker.pendown()
for _ in range(4):
    marker.forward(BOX_SIZE)
    marker.left(90)

difficulty = int(screen.numinput("difficulty", "Enter a difficulty from 1 to 5", minval=1, maxval=5))

cat = Turtle()
cat.shapesize(2)
cat.penup()

mouse = Turtle()
mouse.penup()
mouse.goto(200, 200)

# add key listeners
screen.onkeypress(up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(right, 'Left')
screen.onkeypress(left, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(back, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(screen.bye, 'Escape')
screen.listen()

screen.ontimer(move, 1000)  # give player a chance to move hand from keyboard to mouse

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: It was the first program from a book I am reading "learning python with raspberry pi"...so it was my first time with such type of complicated program but i solved the bugs and executed the code so thanx